# Disable formatting in ReSharper/Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, resharper

Is there a simple way to disable automatic formatting for a specific file in Visual Studio 2008 using ReSharper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ReSharper 7 (and few prior versions) you can specify generated files masks, those will not be formatted.

ReSharper->Options->Code Inspection->Generated Code->Generated file masks

For example if I have a file that contains reference data (as an array, for example), I call file for example States.data.cs and add *.data.cs to generated files masks list.

Comment: Current version of ReSharper is 6.1

Comment: 6.1 has that for sure. I use ReSharper 7 EAP

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK, there is no option to conditionally disable the Auto-Format by file type or specific file with ReSharper 4.5. The only option is to enable/disable for all files:

> ReSharper > Options > Editor: Auto-format on semicolon/closing brace

Comment: This did not work for me because Resharper formats also when doing refactorings / quick tip changes. To preserve the existing formatting the following setting helped for me:

'Resharper > Options > Formatting style > Line Breaks and wrapping > Keep existing line breaks'