# Resharper refactoring/formatting code on rebuild or clean if caret is in the end of the string

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper

m encountering a weird issue in resharper that only happens if you set the caret (cursor) on the end even with default settings.

Example code:

```
if ( something )
{
    doThis();
}
```

After selecting rebuild solution or clean solution, resharper will modify the code up to do this, if the caret while editing is after `;`:

```
if ( something )
{doThis();
}
```

or when if after `}`:

```
if ( something )
{
    doThis();}
```

And is pretty annoying, i have tried solutions posted in:

- [Disable formatting in ReSharper/Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613982/visual-studio-resharper-disable-formatting)
- [Is there any way to turn off Resharper 7 auto formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718947/is-there-any-way-to-turn-off-resharper-7-auto-formatting)

But nothing happen.
So please help, this bug is really annoying

Kindest Regards

Comment: What version of Resherper are you using? Have you tried disabling Resharper to see if you get the same results? Do you have any other extenstions installed?

Comment: Version 8.0.2000.2660, Disabled reshaper and behavior stop happening so it must be resharper, no other visual studio extensions installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

After a complete reinstall of the suite and resetting to defaults options everything went fine, m steel unable to locate what produced this behavior even after exporting the options and comparing there were same so its a weird issue.

Kindest Regards